# Three20: variableHeightRows on a searchViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20

I couldn't get variableHeightRows to work on a search view controller.

```
TTTableViewController* searchController = [[TTTableViewController alloc] init];

searchController.dataSource = [[[SomeDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
searchController.variableHeightRows = YES; // this doesn't affect the table

self.searchViewController = searchController;
[searchController release];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
_searchController.pausesBeforeSearching = YES;
[_searchController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
```

It always show the rows in the default height. On my regular table view with the same datasource, the height of the rows is set to the custom one I supply in `+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)object`, but specifically not on the search controller.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep investigation...

I set the delegate of the search controller to the same class (`[_searchController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];`), something which prevented from a TTTableViewVarHeightDelegate delegate to be created, therefore, the custom heightForRowAtIndexPath wasn't called. I added:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  id<TTTableViewDataSource> dataSource = (id<TTTableViewDataSource>)tableView.dataSource;

  id object = [dataSource tableView:tableView objectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  Class cls = [dataSource tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object];
  return [cls tableView:tableView rowHeightForObject:object];
}
```

to the TTTableViewController class (source of TTTableViewVarHeightDelegate) and it worked.